# wrong schema in case of dataframe obtained from ORC hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

- Spark version: 1.6.1
- HDP: 2.4.2

---

I have a hive table in Hive with ORC format.

```
CREATE TABLE `test01_orc`(
  `c1` int, 
  `c2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
 .......
```

Useful code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("DCA_HIVE_HDFS");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(sc);
DataFrame df = hc.table("testdb.test01_orc");
df.printSchema();
```

output:

```
 root
  |-- _col0: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- _col1: string (nullable = true)
```

**`_col0` and `_col1` as column names while I already mentioned these as `c1` and `c2`**

In case of hive table with other formats like TEXTFILE, SEQUENCEFILE, RCFILE, PARQUET and AVRO:

```
root
  |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
```

Is this a bug or is there any configuration changes needed to do this?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: can't you just rename your columns?

Comment: @mtoto Did my updated question make sense?

Comment: I am not famililar with `ORC` format but perhaps lose the quotes around the colnames as in `CREATE TABLE test01_orc(
  c1 int, 
  c2 string)`